# JavaScript get img src in string

Tags: javascript, regex

```
data = "<p><img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j//9k=">Note: example</p><p>today</p>"

Expected result
data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j//9k=

Code
var m, regex = (/<p[^>]+<img[^>]+src="data:image([^">]+)/g);
m = regex.exec(data);

console.log(data);//null
```

I'm trying to get the encoded base64 image src in a string using regex to display in my textarea but I always get the `null` result in the console log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're going to use regex, here is a simple solution:

```js
const data = '<p><img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j//9k=">Note: example</p><p>today</p>';

const regex = /<img.*?src=['"](.*?)['"]/;

console.log(regex.exec(data)[1]);
```

If you're using jQuery:

```js
console.log($('img').attr('src'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p><img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j//9k=">Note: example</p>
<p>today</p>
```

If you wish to use plain javascript:

```js
console.log(document.getElementById('img-id').src);
```

```html
<p><img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j//9k=" id="img-id">Note: example</p>
<p>today</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```js
let data = '<p><img src="data: image / jpeg; base64, /9j/ / 9k = ">Note: example</p><p>today</p>';

var m, regex = (/".+"/g);
m = regex.exec(data)[0];
m = m.slice(1, m.length - 1);

console.log(m);
```